# How to use javascript lookup table inside typescript map method?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I use a simple JavaScript [lookup table](https://medium.com/@omwri/javascript-patterns-lookup-tables-26bbaf693e24) (which is the mapping itself) inside map function?
I.e how can i get rid of this `"code"` field (borrowed from [here](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/keyof-and-lookup-types-in-typescript)), and use only the lookup table inside `map` method?

```js
const Resistors = {
    "black": 0,    "brown": 1,    "red": 2,
    "orange": 3,   "yellow": 4,   "green": 5,
    "blue": 6,     "violet": 7,   "grey": 8,
    "white": 9,

    // Why not Resistors[color]
    "code" : (color: string) => {
        function valueOf<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) {
            return obj[key];
        }
        return valueOf(Resistors, color as any);
    }
}
class ResistorColor {
    private colors: string[];
    constructor(colors: string[]) { this.colors = colors; }
    value = () => {
        return Number.parseInt(
            this.colors
                  .map(Resistors.code) // How can i get rid of .code here?
                  .join("")
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what you're doing already?

Comment: @zerkms I use an auxilary field as mapping function, I'd rather prefer something like
`.map(x => Lookup[x])`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a little hard to know exactly what you're looking for, but at a glance ... you can!  You should be able to do:

```js
const Resistors = {
  black: 0,
  brown: 1,
}
```

And then...

```js
const numericColorCode = Resistors['black'];
console.log(numericColorCode) // should be 0
```

Now sometimes the TypeScript compiler can get grumpy about this kind of thing.  You may need to do something like this to make the compiler happy:

```js
const numericColorCode = (Resistors as {[index: string]: number})['black'];
```

As for your question below that - use `Object.keys` and a `Array.join`!

```js
const allTheColors = Object.keys(Resistors).join(',');
console.log(allTheColors); // should be 'black,brown'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a way to use lookup table inside map. This works: 
`this.colors.map((color: string)=> (Resistors as {[index: string]: number})[color])`

Comment: Can you pinpoint a name for this idiom or some kind keyword for looking it up in docs? It would be nice, if your example used map method

Comment: You're just reading a property from an object. Don't make up "patterns" out of nothing.

Comment: So `map` is really only useful when you want to iterate over the values in an array, and then transform them into something else.  Are you trying to effectively take an array of property names, and turn that into an array of values?

Comment: Yes, can I do a multiple key lookup instead? This is the exercise https://github.com/exercism/problem-specifications/issues/1464.

Answer (score 1):

Further to - and based on - Justin's answer, here's another example around *where* to define your types:

```js
const messages: {[index: string]: string} = {
  'required': 'The value is required',
  'minimumValue': 'The value is not large enough'
}

const validationErrorType = 'required';
const messageToUser = messages[validationErrorType];
```